# Excel automatic "date changed" field for each column of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I'm using Windows Excel 2007, if that matters, and I'm trying to have a date field update to today's date automatically only when a cell in that column gets changed.

I add new data entries per column and want "date changed" entries automatically displayed and updated in row 7 after columns A and B but only after those two header columns, and let's say if row 7 isn't blank or made blank, I want automatic date keeping to expand for a new entry.

I've looked for a solution and found the NOW() formula, but that's not quite right. I've found a few similar things, but I don't know enough about macros to change them to my desired effect.

How do I do what I've described? It may be a macro or formula.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You Will need to go to VBA and work with the worksheet_change procedure.  You can determine the row that was changed and then change the date on that row.  The NOW() won't work because it will always show the current date.

Comment: if i got you right, then it is possible without vba... but i need something like a sample to really get what you want (picture or workbook)

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column > 2 Then Cells("1", Target.Column) = Now()
End Sub
```

And it works wonderfully. Although, I foresee some unnecessary operations.